# File Format and Extension doesn't match

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

I wrote a code to export the data from a VF page. However, when i try to open download the exported page i get a warning message saying the File Format & extension doesn't match. Please help me resolve this warning message.

Comment: Please show your actual Visualforce code.

Comment: How are we supposed to find the issue when you haven't provided us with the key to the secret code?!

Answer (score 0):

Is that MS Excel complaining about file that pretends to be real *.xslx file but actual payload is CSV or even a HTML with `<table>` in it? Well, not much you can do about it.

Excel can try to parse unexpected content, no idea if you can disable that warning somehow. I doubt you'll be able to really please Excel gods. If you tell it it's *.xslx it'll expect a directory full of xml documents, zipped (make a "real" Excel file, force rename it to *.zip, try to open and you'll see what I mean). You won't be able to make a zip file with pure VF and Apex, maybe with some crazy JavaScript libraries...

Just dismiss the warning and move on? Or generate CSV?